# Does vscode support session setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have default user settings configured, but I need to tweak the settings only for this opened vscode session. Does vscode support this?

or do we have any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change settings for a "session" of vscode; however, it is possible to specify settings for a workspace. A workspace is the current open folder.

Type `Ctrl+Shift+P` and search for Workspace Settings.

Comment: Yes i am aware of workspace setting management but i need to open from folder but i am looking for handling different settings without folder based.

Comment: May be then as workaround i am thinking of using junction based user settings file so that i can switch